# How to calculate the Gibbs free energy for a reaction?

Tags: vasp, thermodynamics, free-energy

I am trying to learn how to calculate Gibbs free energy for a reaction. Assuming a reaction for two-dimensional TMDCs:

MoS2 (solid) + 2Se(gas) ---> MoSe2 (solid)+ 2S (gas)

I can calculate the energies of terms, e.g., single-layer MoS2 (solid) and MoSe2 (solid). Perhaps for S and Se energies of a single atom is a box but all these values are at 0K and does not includes temperature (T) effects.

Now, I am wondering: How can I study this reaction?

It would be extremely useful to have some insight.
Thanks

Update:
For S(gas), I performed frequency analysis. For a given value of temperature and pressure, using vaspkit, it shows the following result. [image]

It shows that the thermal correction to G(T) is -1.603737. Should I add this value to the E_0?
i.e., S(gas) = E_0 + G(T) = -0.03107224-1.6037 = −1.63477224
and this will be the energy for S(gas) with Gibbs free energy correction?

Comment: From a thermodynamic point, you will need to know the chemical potential of Te and Se in the gas phase. They will have different values if the gas is 50:50 Te:Se or 99:1 Te:Se and so forth. You could probably assume ideal gas, and deal with mixture properties that way, and get the ideal gas free energies from vacuum calculations. A similar issue will occur in the solid phase. I would be tempted to do alchemical mutation of an Se in the solid to Te in the solid, and Te in gas to Se in gas. I think you might even be able to do this using DFT nowadays, almost certainly with MM you could

Comment: thanks for the response. I did this with DFT at 0K, and the above equation gives MoS2 + 2Se (-21.9068 eV) ----> MoSe2 + 2S (-20.0404 eV). As the energy of reactants is lower than products, it will be an endothermic reaction. However, these values are at 0K. I want to calculate the same at say 400 C (673 K). How can this be accomplished?

Comment: A frequency analysis on a single molecule will give you the free energy of your gas at a desired temperature, and a phonon analysis on a solid will give you your free energy of your solid at your desired temperature. However, you should still be accounting for composition I would think, in both solid and gas phases. How the reaction proceeds will change as the reaction progresses - you will eventually hit an equilibrium composition

Comment: I have updated the above question as per your suggestion, by adding frequency analysis for S(gas). Can you please confirm if this is what you were suggesting?

Comment: That is the right idea, however I can't validate which value to use since I have never used VASP unfortunately, so I am not sure how they go from E(T=0K) to G(T=673). For single molecule properties though, you can probably get better G's using Gaussian with a something made for accurate thermochemistry, say, `G4` https://gaussian.com/gn/

Comment: Are you able to copy-and-paste that output into a `code` block rather than using a screenshot? Pictures won't load for some people, and on some browsers, and reading them is impossible for blind people using screen readers. The text in the also can't be searched.

Comment: How did this go? Did you figure it out?